# How to parse HTML full page in android

Tags: android, html-parsing

I am calling a HTML page via a web servise . I need to get hole source code of HTML page.
My problem is that, when I convert the http response to string I am getting only some part of HTML page. How do I can get hole HTML page .Please help me.

```
//paramString1 = url,paramString = header, paramList = paramiters
public String a(String paramString1, String paramString2, List paramList)
  {
    String str1 = null; 
    HttpPost localHttpPost = new HttpPost(paramString1);
    localHttpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    InputStream localInputStream = null;
   try
     {

    localHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramList));
    localHttpPost.setHeader("Referer", paramString2);
    HttpResponse localHttpResponse = this.c.execute(localHttpPost);
    int i = localHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    localInputStream = localHttpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    Header localHeader = localHttpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
    if ((localHeader != null) && (localHeader.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")))
    {
         GZIPInputStream localObject = null;
      localObject = new GZIPInputStream(localInputStream);
      Log.d("API", "GZIP Response decoded!");
      BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream)localObject, "UTF-8"));
      StringBuilder localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      while(true){
          String str2 = localBufferedReader.readLine();
          if (str2 == null)
            break;
          localHttpResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
          str1 = localStringBuilder.toString();
          localStringBuilder.append(str2);
          continue;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (IOException localIOException)
  {
    localHttpPost.abort();

  }
  catch (Exception localException)
  {
    localHttpPost.abort();

  }
  Object localObject = localInputStream;

return (String)str1;
```

Comment: it may be because of stringbuilder is not able to store the complete sourcecode of the HTML page.

Comment: then what is the other way to store complete sourcecode .can you please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving the HTML in the variable paramString1?, in that case, are you encoding the String somehow or its just plane HTML?

Maybe the HTML special characters are breaking your response. Try encoding the String with urlSafe Base64 in your server side, and decoding it in the client side:

You can use the function Base64 of Apache Commons.

Server Side:

```
Base64 encoder = new Base64(true);
encoder.encode(yourBytes);
```

Client side:

```
Base64 decoder = new Base64(true);
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(paramString1);
HttpPost localHttpPost = new HttpPost(new String(decodedBytes));
```

Comment: no paramString1 is my Url. I am receiving HTML response in localHttpResponse .

Answer (score 0):

You may not get the complete source code in your stringBuilder as it must be exceeding the max size of stringBuilder as `StringBuilder` is set of arrays. If u want to store that particular sourcecode. You may try this: The inputStream (which contains html source code) data,  store directly into a File. Then you will have complete source code in that file and then perform file operation to whatever you require. See if this may help you.

Comment: `StringBuilder`'s size is only limited by the maximum possible `char` array in java which is about 4GB.